# How to represent categorical data in a pie graph form?

Tags: data-visualization, categorical-data, pie-chart

I have been asked to produce a pie graph of some categorical data.

On a simple scale it look like this:

```
House 1: Speak a foreign language , own a computer
House 2: Only lived in by women
House 3: Only lived in by women, speak a foreign language
House 4: Has pets
House 5: Has pets, own a computer
House 6: Speak a foreign language.
```

They want a pie graph that shows what percent of the different categories are represented.

```
Well if I go:
Speak a foreign language  = 3/6
Own a computer = 2/6
Only lived in by women = 2/6
has pets = 2/6
```

This totals 9/6 (i.e more than 100%)

Should I be totalling how many individual items there are and then creating my %'ages from that

i.e

```
Speak a foreign language  = 3/9
Own a computer = 2/9
Only lived in by women = 2/9
has pets = 2/9
```

this makes 100% but i am unsure if this is how you would do it so all the data is shown in one pie graph.

Answer (score 8):

A pie chart - if it's suitable at all - is *only* suitable for mutually exclusive categories, since it represents a division of a whole into mutually exclusive subsets.

So, *don't* use a pie chart for categories that are not mutually exclusive. You're misleading people by doing so. (Why would you want to actively - and seemingly deliberately - mislead people about the information you're presenting?)

*If* you know the overlap in subsets, you might be able to use area to represent proportion, with overlapping area representing the intersection of the categories, but it won't look like a pie.

Alternatively, if possible, use the information you have to break the data *into* mutually exclusive subsets, which can then be represented as a pie chart. (Where possible, arrange those subsets so adjacent subsets combine to give other meaningful subsets)

This 'break into mutually exclusive subsets' and 'represent as a pie chart' will generally be less informative than other choices that represent all available combinations (think along the lines of a Venn-diagram, but with area also representing probability).